# SOLVED Magento 2.3.6 not connect to backend

Tags: magento2.3

while checking the orders in the backend, changing page, the Chrome browser gave me an error:

```
Unable to reach the site
The web page at ... may be temporarily unavailable or has been permanently moved to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

I can no longer access the administrative side, but the site is visible. It happens with all browsers.

How can I resolve and log back into the backend?

UPDATE: Chrome console show error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

[image]

**UPDATE2:** I solve, there was a conflict with an extension. I have disable it and now works

Comment: If you go to your webserver admin in the php error logs, what is the actual error it is encountering?

Comment: Hi Erik I have this error related to admin url: [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4491] (22)Invalid argument: [client 151.61.169.26:40760] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
and Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer:

Comment: In proxy error log there is this: peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 151.61...., server: xxx, request: "GET /tessera/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: